# Highcharts networkgraph datalabels on hover

Tags: angular, highcharts

there!

I have a networkgraph built on highcharts and I need the datalabels to start turned of for some of the points. Then, I want to turn them on whenever user hovers a connected point. For this image, for example, on hovering "Rio de Janeiro", all the 5 points connected to it should have their datalabels on.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initially create all data labels, but hide them by setting opacity style to 0. Then, use `mouseOver` and `mouseOut` events to toggle the opacity.

```
const toggleDLInLinks = (links, isVisible) => {
    links.forEach(link => {
        if (isVisible) {
            link.toNode.dataLabel.css({
                opacity: 1
            })
        } else {
            link.toNode.dataLabel.css({
                opacity: 0
            })
        }

        if (link.toNode.linksFrom.length) {
            toggleDLInLinks(link.toNode.linksFrom, isVisible);
        }
    });
};

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    plotOptions: {
        networkgraph: {
            ...,
            dataLabels: {
                allowOverlap: true,
                enabled: true,
                style: {
                    opacity: 0,
                    transition: ''
                }
            },
            point: {
                events: {
                    mouseOver: function() {
                        const point = this;

                        if (point.linksFrom.length) {
                            toggleDLInLinks(point.linksFrom, true);
                        }
                    },
                    mouseOut: function() {
                        const point = this;
                        if (point.linksFrom.length) {
                            toggleDLInLinks(point.linksFrom);
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            keys: ['from', 'to']
        }
    },
    ...
});
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/5n2u1b3L/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#css

Answer (score 0):

You have provided no code I can only explain what could be done.
We can for example, we listen when user `mouseOver`'s our series and we then turn `dataLabels enabled` for that series and it's children. Everything else get `dataLabels disabled`

```js
series: {
            stickyTracking: true,
            events: {
                mouseOver: function () {
                  var hoverSeries = this;                                      

                  this.chart.series.forEach(function(s){
                    if(s != hoverSeries) {
                      // Turn off other series labels
                      s.update({ 
                        dataLabels: {
                          enabled: false
                        }
                      });                          
                    } else {
                      // Turn on hover series labels
                      hoverSeries.update({ 
                        dataLabels: {
                          enabled: true
                        }
                      });                        
                    }
                  });                                        
                },
                mouseOut: function () {                    
                  this.chart.series.forEach(function(s){
                    // Reset all series
                    s.setState('');
                    s.update({
                      dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true
                      }
                    });                          
                  });                         
                }
            }
        }
```

Some example: https://jsfiddle.net/fakytqhd/